# Google analytics - First Page of First Session Dimension

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, attribution

It should be so simple, that it is frustrating.
There is the famous 'landing page' dimension. However, a 'landing page' is defined as the FIRST page of some session. What dimension shows the FIRST page of the FIRST session of a user? For example, when I create a report, that shows for every custom event (==goal/conversion) the landing_page, I see the landing page of the session in which the event was sent. But I want to see the data (landing page, source, referral) of the FIRST session. This is also called First Touch attribution. But I can't find a way to change it. I should be simple, and I can't find any information about it.

Comment: I can only think of analyzing this with SQL in BQ or further ETLing the data somewhere and conducting this analysis there.

Comment: Yes, but it's super weird that such basic thing - knowing the referral or landing page of the first session of a user that accomplished a specific goal (e.g. purchased) is impossible.

Comment: I'm not sure it's impossible, but generally, GA4's interface is much weaker than UA's. But even UA's interface is only appropriate for smaller businesses that don't dig too deep. Middle-sized businesses tend to leverage Google Data Studio. The bigger corps either use enterprise analytics like Adobe Analytics for advanced analysis and data science, or just ETLing the data from GA360 to BQ and then to their own datalakes where they can build proper custom attribution logic with no limits. You can try asking on measure slack.

Comment: So basically Google Analytics is useless. The Google Data studio does not create/collect new data right? It justs show a bunch of data sources in one place, so it is not a solution for me right?

Comment: Well, technically, GA collects all the data needed to conduct your analysis. It's just it's not easy to get the first touch landing page through GA's interface. We never need it. We use campaign tracking directly, and then from the campaign we know what the landing is. Data Studio may present more SQL-like tools for filtering. I use looker, and it definitely does the trick, but then again LookML is very close to SQL.